# mongo - read Preference design strategy

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I have an application for which I am tasked with designing a mongo backed data storage.

The application goals are to provide the latest data ( no stale data ) with the fastest load times.

The data size is in the order of a few millions with the application being write heavy.

In choosing what the read strategy is given a 3-node replica set ( 1 primary, 1 secondary, 1 arbiter ), I came across two different strategies to determine where to source the reads from -

- Read from the secondary to reduce load on primary. With the `writeConcern = REPLICA_SAFE`, thus ensuring the writes are done on both primary and the secondary. Set the read preference. to `secondaryPreferred`.
- Always read from primary. but ensure the data is in primary before reading. So set  `writeConcern= SAFE` . The read preference is default - `primaryPreferred` .

What are the things to be considered before choosing one of the options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation [REPLICA_SAFE](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html#REPLICAS_SAFE) is a deprecated term and should be replaced with [REPLICA_ACKNOWLEDGED](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html#REPLICA_ACKNOWLEDGED). The other problem here is that the `w` value here appears to be **2** from this constant.

This is a problem for your configuration, as you have your Primary and *only one* Secondary, combined with an arbiter. In the event of a *node* going down, or being otherwise unreachable, with the level set as this it is looking to acknowledge all writes from **2 nodes** where there will not be **2 nodes** available. You can leave write operations hanging in this way.

The better case for your configuration would be [MAJORITY](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html#MAJORITY), as no matter the number of nodes it will ensure writes to the Primary and the "majority" of the secondaries. **But** in your case any write concern condition involving **more than the PRIMARY** will **block** on **all writes**, if one of your nodes is down or unavailable, as you would have to have **at least two more** secondary nodes available so that there would still be a "majority" of nodes to acknowledge the write. Or drop the ARBITER and have two SECONDARY nodes.

So you will have to stick to the default `w=1` where all writes are acknowledged to the PRIMARY unless you can deal with writes failing when your **one** SECONDARY goes down.

You can set the *read preference* to `secondaryPreferred` as long as you accept that you can ""possibly" be reading stale or not the latest representation of your data as the only **real** guarantee is of a write to the Primary node. The general replication considerations remain, in that the nodes should be somewhat equal in processing capability or this can lead to lag or general performance degradation as a result of your query operations.

Remember that replication is implemented for **redundancy** and is not a system for **improving performance**. If you are looking for *performance* then perhaps look into scaling up your system hardware or implement sharding to distribute the load.

Comment: Just a clarification.  MAJORITY is based on the number of nodes in the configuration.  Not the number of running nodes. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/#available-write-concern

Comment: +1 for clarifying that that replication is for redundancy rather than for performance improvement.

Comment: the reason we have replicas is to increase the availability and distribute the load among replica sets which means performance boost